# webpack exclude property vs webpack-node-externals package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

In webpack server config file,

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  }
```

exclude means do not compile those directories, in this case it is only node_modules. However there is also `webpack-node-externals` package.

```
const nodeWebExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
  externals: [nodeWebExternals()],
```

externals property inside module.exports object is going to tell webpack not to bundle any libraries into our output bundle on the server if that library exists inside the node-modules folder.

What is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2):

The `exclude` option tells to `babel-loader` not to transform (modern syntax to es5) inside `node_modules` folder. Without `externals` part, webpack will not transform the syntax but will **bundle** each `node_module` that is in use to the final bundle.

Usually when bundle server code, there is **no need** to bundle `node_modules` because it is exists in the server as a folder, therefore, you are telling webpack to mark those modules as `externals`, it will generate a regular node `require` to the module instead of the modules code.